No se eliminan elementos del UI
En mi aplicacion tkinter tengo una funcion que genera un boton por cada elemento de una Lista, el clickear un boton deberia eliminar el elemento del que se basa de la lista y actualizar el UI para que ya no salga dicho elemento, pero al clickear alguno unicamente se elimina de la Lista mas no del UI e incluso el siguiente elemento de la lista se pone por encima del boton que no deberia estar:

esta es mi funcion de eliminar productos:
def eliminar_producto(index):
        if not productos_ventana or index >= len(productos_ventana):
            return

        del productos_ventana[index]
        del botones_eliminar[index]

        for i, boton in enumerate(botones_eliminar):
            boton.grid_forget()
            boton.grid(row=i + 3, column=0)

        print(productos_ventana)
        calcular_total()


Primero de todo, es importante entender que:
del botones_eliminar[index]

está eliminando el objeto tk.Button de la lista, pero eso no implica que el objeto sea eliminado en memoria y destruido, simplemente pierde una referencia.
Por otro lado, tkinter es solo una interfaz para el interprete tcl/tk que se ejecuta debajo. Que elimines la referencia al widget en Python no implica que el widgets sea destruido en tcl/tk y deje de mostrarse.
tkinter mantiene una referencia propia a todo widgets vivo, aunque elimines cualquier referencia al widgets que tengas, siempre quedará esta referencia interna y el objeto no será destruido por el recolector de basura:
>>> import tkinter as tk 
>>> import gc
>>> import weakref

>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> btn = tk.Button(root)
>>> btn.pack()

>>> r = weakref.ref(btn)
>>> r
<weakref at 0x7076efd3a4d0; to 'Button' at 0x7076efc53ce0>

>>> del btn
>>> gc.collect()
>>> r
<weakref at 0x7076efd3a4d0; to 'Button' at 0x7076efc53ce0>

Para eliminar el widget debes llamar a su método destroy() explícitamente. Esto destruye el windgets en tcl/tk, (dejando de mostrarse por tanto) y elimina la referencia interna del lado de tkinter. Luego, si el resto de referencias son eliminadas, el objeto sera recolectado:
>>> r = weakref.ref(btn)
>>> r
<weakref at 0x71dbb66fa4d0; to 'Button' at 0x7076efc53ce0>

>>> btn.destroy()
>>> del btn
>>> gc.collect()
>>> r
<weakref at 0x71dbb66fa4d0; dead>

En tu caso, como el widget no es destruido, sigue posicionado en la misma celda, como luego el for no itera sobre el simplemente posiciona otro de los botones en la misma celda.
Simplemente tienes que destruirlo, o dejar de mostrarlo con grid_forget()/grid_remove() si planeas reutilizar el botón después:
botones_eliminar[index].destroy()
del botones_eliminar[index]

o más directamente:
...

del productos_ventana[index]
botones_eliminar.pop(index).destroy()

for i, boton in enumerate(botones_eliminar):
    ...

